# Tkinter menu for chosing a date

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter

I am building a dropdown menu that would be used to choose a starting date. It has 3 cascades named year, month, day. The contents of the day cascade is generated so that the available days are true to the chosen year and month.
It is possible/probable that the user is going to change the date several times during a single session.

My problem: When the user selects the year/month for the first time, the days commands get generated. Thereafter any new year/month combination, the following code just adds the commands to the cascade. So that the day cascade contains the days of two months.

[image]

I have been trying to make the code remove the old menubar entry daymenu and recreate it based on the new data. 
I would like to know, how does one do such changes to a preexisting, running menubar? I have searched the tkinter documentation, but could not out how to implement it.

```
import calendar as cal
import Tkinter as tk
import datetime
import os.path
window = tk.Tk()



# Menu variables:
year = tk.IntVar()
month = tk.IntVar()
day = tk.IntVar()
hour = tk.IntVar()
minute = tk.IntVar()
dur_hour = tk.IntVar()
dur_minute = tk.IntVar()
duration = tk.StringVar()
start = tk.StringVar()

#            list initializations    

list_of_years = []
list_of_months = []
list_of_hours = []
list_of_days = []
list_of_minutes = []


def year_seter(value):
    year.set(value)
    all_for_day()

def all_for_day(): #checks if the data needed to determine number of days in the month is present
    list_of_days = []
    y = year.get()
    m = month.get()
    lenght_of_month = cal.monthrange(y,m)
    lenght_of_month2 = lenght_of_month[1]
    if m != 0 and y != 0:
        make_daylist(lenght_of_month2)
        make_daymenu()

def month_seter(value):
    month.set(value)
    all_for_day()

def day_seter(value):
    day.set(value)

def time_parameters():
    the_date = datetime.datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
    the_date = the_date.now()
    end_year = the_date.year  
    make_yearlist(1995, end_year)
    make_monthlist()
    make_hourlist()
    make_minutelist()

def make_yearlist(the_year, end_year):
    while the_year <= end_year:
        list_of_years.append(the_year)
        the_year += 1

def make_monthlist():
    for i in range(12):
        list_of_months.append(i + 1)

def make_daylist(num_days):
    for i in range(num_days):
        list_of_days.append(i + 1)

def make_hourlist():
    for i in range(24):
        list_of_hours.append(i)

def make_minutelist():
    for i in range(60):
        list_of_minutes.append(i)

def make_daymenu():
    for the_day in list_of_days:
        daymenu.add_command(label=the_day, command=lambda : day_seter(the_day))
    window.config(menu=menubar)



# The following constructs the menu
time_parameters()
menubar = tk.Menu(window)

yearmenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
for the_year in list_of_years:
    yearmenu.add_command(label=str(the_year), command=lambda the_year=the_year: year_seter(the_year))
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'Year', menu=yearmenu)
window.config(menu=menubar)

monthmenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
for the_month in list_of_months:
    monthmenu.add_command(label=the_month, command=lambda the_month=the_month: month_seter(the_month))
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'Month', menu=monthmenu)
window.config(menu=menubar)  

daymenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'Day', menu=daymenu)
window.config(menu=menubar)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete all entries in `daymenu` before adding new ones:

```
def make_daymenu():
    daymenu.delete(0,31) 
    for the_day in list_of_days:
        daymenu.add_command(label=the_day, command=lambda : day_setter(the_day))
    window.config(menu=menubar)
```

Comment: of course, all months have at least 28 days, so all you need to add or remove anything more than that.

Comment: @ByanOakley: I don't quite know how to implement what you are suggesting. It isn't as simple as using `daymenu.delete(29,31)`, since that would duplicate days 1..28. Restricting the for-loop to add only the needed days would require finding out what days are already in the menu. How does one do that?

Comment: I have thought about that solution also, but I am still learning the basics so I have no idea how to implement it. Anyways thanks to both of you for your input.

Comment: @unutbu: once you fill the menu tne first time, it will always have at least 28 entries. It just takes the tiniest bit of math to figure out the menu index for each day, and there are ways to get the index of the last item. In your case it will be easier to just recreate the menu every time.

Answer (score 0):

came across your code to select a date. Recently had to write a simple calendar for similar purposes. I can offer you that option as an alternative. I think this option is more convenient to choose the date.

```
import calendar, datetime, Tkinter

class calendarTk(Tkinter.Frame): # class calendarTk
    """ Calendar, the current date is exposed today, or transferred to date"""
    def __init__(self,master=None,date=None,dateformat="%d/%m/%Y",command=lambda i:None):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.dt=datetime.datetime.now() if date is None else datetime.datetime.strptime(date, dateformat) 
        self.showmonth()
        self.command=command
        self.dateformat=dateformat
    def showmonth(self): # Show the calendar for a month
        sc = calendar.month(self.dt.year, self.dt.month).split('\n')
        for t,c in [('<<',0),('<',1),('>',5),('>>',6)]: # The buttons to the left to the right year and month
            Tkinter.Button(self,text=t,relief='flat',command=lambda i=t:self.callback(i)).grid(row=0,column=c)
        Tkinter.Label(self,text=sc[0]).grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=3) # year and month
        for line,lineT in [(i,sc[i+1]) for i in range(1,len(sc)-1)]: # The calendar
            for col,colT in [(i,lineT[i*3:(i+1)*3-1]) for i in range(7)]: # For each element
                obj=Tkinter.Button if colT.strip().isdigit() else Tkinter.Label # If this number is a button, or Label
                args={'command':lambda i=colT:self.callback(i)} if obj==Tkinter.Button else {} # If this button, then fasten it to the command
                bg='green' if colT.strip()==str(self.dt.day) else 'SystemButtonFace' # If the date coincides with the day of date - make him a green background
                fg='red' if col>=5 else 'SystemButtonText' # For the past two days, the color red
                obj(self,text="%s"% colT,relief='flat',bg=bg,fg=fg,**args).grid(row=line, column=col, ipadx=2, sticky='nwse') # Draw Button or Label
    def callback(self,but): # Event on the button
        if but.strip().isdigit():  self.dt=self.dt.replace(day=int(but)) # If you clicked on a date - the date change
        elif but in ['<','>','<<','>>']:
            day=self.dt.day
            if but in['<','>']: self.dt=self.dt+datetime.timedelta(days=30 if but=='>' else -30) # Move a month in advance / rewind
            if but in['<<','>>']: self.dt=self.dt+datetime.timedelta(days=365 if but=='>>' else -365) #  Year forward / backward
            try: self.dt=self.dt.replace(day=day) # We are trying to put the date on which stood
            except: pass                          # It is not always possible
        self.showmonth() # Then always show calendar again
        if but.strip().isdigit(): self.command(self.dt.strftime(self.dateformat)) # If it was a date, then call the command

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def com(f): print f
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Monthly Calendar")
    c=calendarTk(root,date="21/11/2006",dateformat="%d/%m/%Y",command=com)
    c.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```